# construct sequence of calls to void method with thrown exceptions in NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I have an interface I'm mocking out

```
public interface IFoo {
    void Bar(IEnumerable<int>);
}
```

My code under test calls Bar() a few times in sequence. I want to define my unit test such that Bar throws an exception the 2nd (or Nth) time it is called. Is there a succinct way to do so? I've found an example for non-void methods: http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/multiple-returns/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### Callbacks for void calls
>
> `Returns()` can be used to get callbacks for members that return a value, but for `void` members we need a different technique, because we can’t call a method on a `void` return. For these cases we can use the `When..Do` syntax.
>
> ### Callback builder for more complex callbacks
>
> The `Callback` builder lets us create more complex `Do()` scenarios. We can use `Callback.First()` followed by `Then()`, `ThenThrow()` and `ThenKeepDoing()` to build chains of callbacks. We can also use `Always()` and `AlwaysThrow()` to specify callbacks called every time. Note that a callback set by an `Always()` method will be called even if other callbacks will throw an exception.

So for your scenario you can setup the substitute like

```
var foo = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
foo
    .When(_ => _.Bar(Arg.Any<IEnumerable<int>>()))
    .Do(Callback
        .First(_ => _)//First time do nothing
        .ThenThrow(new Exception()) //second time throw the provided exception
    );
```

Reference [Callbacks, void calls and When..Do](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks/)

Comment: Thanks for this - not sure why, but I had misunderstood the usage and had `.Do(_ => Callback.First(...).Then(...).Then(...))` which caused an endless loop. Once I stopped tring to make it a func it worked as expected. Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees.